# Adding image property as new band in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I calculated an image collection with the property "date". Now I want to add the property "date" as a new band but I got the error "Actual value for parameter 'id' must be a constant". Instead of `.getString` I also tried `.get` and `.getNumber`.

[GEEscript](https://code.earthengine.google.com/bb0a316d9d8f61de44345009f88fc941)

```
// Add band:
var add_band = function(img) {
  var bandDate = img.getString('Date');
  return img.addBands(bandDate);
}

var new_mask = s1_mask.map(add_band);
print('ImageCollection new mask', new_mask)
```

And is it possible to transform the new band in a date format such as YYYY_MM_DD?

---

---EDIT--- -> solution

```
var addDate = function(image){
  var dateNum = ee.Image(image).date().millis()
  var doyBand = ee.Image.constant(dateNum).rename('date').toFloat()
  doyBand = doyBand.updateMask(image.select('VV').mask())
  
  return image.addBands(doyBand);
};

var withDate = s1.map(addDate);
print(withDate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple answer: no. The error in your script already tells you that `.addBands()` requires a constant value so no character/string. See for example: [Add a date (day of year) band to each image in a collection using Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268234/add-a-date-day-of-year-band-to-each-image-in-a-collection-using-google-earth-e)

```
  var dateNum = ee.Image(img).date().millis() // date in milli seconds
  var dateBand = ee.Image.constant(dateNum).uint16().rename('dateMillis')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0013a119e3d19bf254196afd5418263b

---

EDIT

Sorry bit of a typo there:

```
var dateBand = ee.Image.constant(dateNum).rename('dateMillis')
```

You can check all your dates by retrieving the computed value from the properties (see example) or add your images and use the inquiry to see the different date bands.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6f72be06fac2ac0b71e2815d155c2e7b

Comment: Thank you. The link to the other post helped (see updated question). But I don't know how to change the format in a way that I have the information about day, month and year.

Comment: If you read the documentation you'll notice that .millis() returns the exact date but expressed in a different format: 
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-date-millis

Comment: Ok, I replaced "var doy = image.date().getRelative('day', 'year');" with "var doy = ee.Image(image).date().millis()". Now I have a new band "dateMillis" but the value is always 65535 although the images were taken on different dates. In your script, this happens as well but you add it also as a new property and this seems to work. So why not with the addBands function?

Comment: Thanks! With your edit it worked but I got another error when I added the image collection to the map. I could fix that with the function .toFloat(). The final code is as an update in my question.